# how to define list variable when your using workspace in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have cidr_blocks which which is list. How can i define different environment in variable for list ??

example:

```
variable "ingress_cidr_blocks" { 
    type            = "list"       
    default         = ["0.0.0.0/0"]        
}

variable "ingress_cidr_blocks" { 
    type            = "list"       
    dev             = ["0.0.0.0/0"]        
}

variable "ingress_cidr_blocks" { 
    type            = "list"       
    uat             = ["0.0.0.0/0"]        
}
```

how can it be converted into

```
variable "sg_name" {
    default = {
        default     = "tf_sg_default",
        dev         = "tf_sg_dev",
        uat         = "tf_sg_uat"
    }
}
```

this is string i wanted same thing for list type

Comment: You can create a `local.sg_name` value, but not `variable`.

Answer (score 0):

> how can it be converted into

It can't. Default value [can't reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) other objects:

> The default argument requires a literal value and **cannot reference** other objects in the configuration.

#### Update:

```
variable "security_groups_w" {
     type = "map" 
      default = {
        default  = "sg-0fdc9fa416cad5ec3"
        dev = "sg-0fdc9fa416cad5ec3"
        uat = "sg-0fdc9fa416cad5ec3" 
      }
}
```

Comment: By bad what is correct syntax of declaring list varaible while working with workspace in terraform

variable "security_groups_w" { 
    type            = "list"  
 default ={
  default     = ["sg-0fdc9fa416cad5ec3"]     
  dev         = ["sg-0fdc9fa416cad5ec3"]  
  uat         = ["sg-0fdc9fa416cad5ec3"]  
 }
}

Comment: If you are can we can't then how people work with list while using workspaces